# TikZ Tree: Change style of specific tree edges

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I want to change the style of some edges of my tree. I want a dashed red path from to root to one leaf of my tree. But if I change some specific edges, all edges below also change. Even the labels are getting red what I do not want.

So that is what happens:

[image]

But I want something like that:

[image]

Any suggestions? It can't be so hard. But I spend over an hour trying to find out. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,svgnames]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata,backgrounds}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.6}


\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
  every node/.style={thin}]
  \node {1}
    child {node {00}
      child {node {00}}
      child {node {}}
      child {node {10}}
      child {node {}}
    }
    child {node {}}
    child {node {10}
    child {node {00} edge from parent[dashed, very thick, red]
    child {node {00}}  
    child {node {01}}
    child {node {10}}
    child {node {11} edge from parent[dashed, very thick, red]}
    }
    child {node {}}
    child {node {}}
    child {node {11}}
    }
    child {node {}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Forest`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package with a simple syntax to customize every edges of your tree, just insert edge options like this

```
edge={dashed,red,thick}
```

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,svgnames]{standalone} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={delay={where content={}{content={\phantom{00}}}{}},s sep+=5mm,l+=5mm}
[1
  [00
     [00]
     []
     [10]
     []  
  ]
  []
  [10,edge={dashed,red,thick} 
     [00,edge={dashed,red,thick}
        [00]
        [01]
        [10]
        [11,edge={dashed,red,thick}]     
     ]
     []
     []
     [11]  
  ]
  [\phantom{00}]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I draw a circle around a given node with a specific size and color?

Comment: For example with root  `[1,circle,fill=red,inner sep=3mm`

Comment: Great! And what if I want only a red circle instead of filled red circle? Where do I find such information? I hope you can help me out.